# How to iterate JSON Serialize objects and assign to the model

Tags: json, vb.net, model-view-controller

Any idea whats the correct way to loop thru JSON object and assign them to the model ?

```
    For Each row As DataRow In dtJson.Rows
        Entities.Context.MyModelObj = Serialization.JSONSerializer.Deserialize(Of MyModelObj)(row.Item("JsonObj"))
    Next row
```

In my case it always assign the last item as expected. But is it possible to assign each items to the model?

Comment: You're only seeing the last item assigned because its overwriting every other item that gets assigned in the loop.

Comment: I do know the problem :) I am trying to find way to do it in the loop for every JSON object

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is fine; the problem is you're not adding to a collection of things, you're overwriting a value

So what you'll want probably is to add each JSON object in a list (please be aware I haven't written vb for about 10 years so I might have my syntax wrong here):

```
Dim objects As New List(Of Entities.Context.MyModelObj);
For Each row As DataRow in dtJson.Rows
    objects.Add(Serialization.JSONSerializer.Deserialize(Of(MyModelObj)(row.Item("JsonObj"))
Next row
```